# New MVC5 project and bundling 404 issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have just created a brand new project and used Nuget to get bootstrap and other js related files.

My Bundles look like the following:

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/Site.css"));
}
}
```

Here is my Layout view:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                @Html.ActionLink("Milford Golfers Association", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

However when the page is debugged I get the following:
[image]

I have tried this with the debug flag set to `false` or `true` in the web config which seemed to be the solution for others.

Comment: How are you rendering the bundles? Please include the code from your view.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had added it, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the [Microsoft.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) Nuget package installed. Without that, the bundle config doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I indeed have the package installed and still receiving the same error

Comment: That's odd. Bundles are really not all that complicated. If you have that nuget package, it should just work. The only other thing that would prevent the bundle from being created is if there's already a directory of the same name. For instance, it's common for a `Content/css` directory to exist, which will break a bundle referenced as `~/Content/css`. However, I doubt that's the case for all of these.

Comment: Perhaps try force removing the package and re-installing it. Maybe it got corrupted somehow. In Package Manager Consolse, run `uninstall-package Microsoft.Web.Optimization -Force` and then `install-package Microsoft.Web.Optimization`. Make sure you have the right project selected in the "Default project" dropdown. Short of that, try generating a new MVC project and getting the bundles working there. Then, you can just move over any files you've added or customized in your existing project.

Comment: Found the issue, turns out when you create a new MVC5 empty project and pull in that nuget package the bit that is missing is `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` from the App_Start.

Comment: Doht. Should have thought of that. Interesting that you didn't just have all this ready to go from the start. Did you literally create a project from scratch, without using the MVC project template?

Comment: My VS didn't give me the option to create a template MVC5 project, had the templates for MVC3/4, I will have to look into it.  I imported the scaffolding for the project which created all the layout files and what not, but it didn't update that particular file.

Comment: Oh. I guess you're using a version of VS less than 2013, then? For 2012, you can install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532 to get most of the same functionality you would have in 2013. You'll need to do that anyways, I think, as a lot of the Razor intellisense will be non-functional without it. If you're running an older version than that, you can't technically develop MVC 5, period. Also, for what it's worth, VS is now on a MSDN model, so if you have an MSDN subscription you can always have the latest version.

Comment: There's also a free version of Visual Studio, now, that is perfectly fine for web development needs.

Comment: Yes I have not upgraded from VS2012, I will check out the free community edition, thank you for your help.